# How to find an attribute that passed in to a component did changed ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

I have a component in ember like

```
 {{some-setup-section
      processingOfId=processingOfId
      savingActivitySetUp=savingActivitySetUp
      editingActivitySetUp=editingActivitySetUp}}
```

and in my components js file

```
didUpdateAttrs() {
 this.updateDataOnChange();
 this._super(...arguments);}
```

I make use of didUpdateAttrs to find when some attribute have changed. In my case I need to exectue a function only when `processingOfId` have changed. Is there any method like `this.attrs('processingOfId').didChanged()` to help me solve my issue.

I tried

```
didUpdateAttrs({oldAttr, newAttr})
```

and check to see if `oldAttr.someAttrs !== newAttr.someAttrs` value but in console it says ember doesn't encourage passing in attrs like that and soon its going to be depricated. Is there any way I can solve this scenario

*To wrap up the question is there any way to find which attribute updated in the 'didUpdateAttrs' method inside a component*

Answer (score 2):

There is no in built way,

1. We have to do it ourself like the below,

Refer [this RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0191-deprecate-component-lifecycle-hook-args.md) for more information.

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  didUpdateAttrs() {
    let oldCoordinates = this.get('_previousCoordinates');
    let newCoordinates = this.get('coordinates');

    if (oldCoordinates && oldCoordinates !== newCoordinates) {
      this.map.move({ from: oldCoordinates, to: newCoordinates });
    }

    this.set('_previousCoordinates', newCoordinates);
  }
});
```

2. You can use addon [ember-diff-attrs](https://github.com/workmanw/ember-diff-attrs).

```
    import diffAttrs from 'ember-diff-attrs';

    export default Ember.Component.extend({
      didReceiveAttrs: diffAttrs('email', 'isAdmin', function(changedAttrs, ...args) {
        this._super(...args);

        if(changedAttrs && changedAttrs.email) {
          let oldEmail = changedAttrs.email[0],
              newEmail = changedAttrs.email[1];
          // Do stuff
        }
      })
    });
```

Some quick notes:

- The function hook provided to diffAttrs will always be called, even when a tracked attr is not changed.
- changedAttrs will be null on the first call.

Refer [addon README](https://github.com/workmanw/ember-diff-attrs) for usage